# Fails to connect through JMX+SSL from VisualVM

Tags: java, ssl, jmx, visualvm, jvisualvm

I have connected a JMX connection from a machine without SSL. But when I give the SSL though the App is getting launched without any error, VisualVM is unable to establish a JMX connection through the specified port. Following is the command I used to establish JMX connection from the App side.

java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4444 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/lib/management/jmxremote.password" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/testkeystore" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true DemoApp

Please advice.

Comment: Did you set up the client side as well? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdevo

Comment: @Klara I did export the keystore from server into a certificate and imported that certificate in my client machine. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: @Klara the JMX connection is failing when I give jmxremote.ssl=true. When its false connection does establish

Comment: Did you set up the javax.net.ssl.trustStore* properties on

Comment: AFAIU, you need to specify a couple of javax.net.ssl.trustStore* properties when starting visualvm, like this: -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path_to/truststore \
  -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustword

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is a quite old question, @Klara's comments helped me to solve the similar issue very fast.

1. First, I needed to prepare my trust store for jVisualVM:

keytool -exportcert -alias server -keystore /jkslocation/serverKS.jks -storepass storepassword -file /certificatelocation/certificate.cer

2. Then I added exported certificate to the trust store:
   keytool -import -alias server -keystore /jkslocation/clientTS.jks -storepass storepassword -file /certificatelocation/certificate.cer -v
3. Then clientTS.jks is copied to the client machine running jVisualVM.
4. jVisualVM is started with trust store parameters:
   ./jvisualvm -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=clientTS.jks -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=clientTSPassword
5. jVisualVM can access server JMX ports.